# Adding a new column whose values are based on another column in either dataframe or excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, excel-formula

I want to add a new column "X" whose values should be either 0 or 1 such that if there exists a value(particularly date in my case) in column "A", it should give 1 or any text 
example:

```
A      | X
----------
*date* | 1
null   | 0
*date* | 1
*date* | 1
*date* | 1
null   | 0
```

any way to do this in pandas or excel/office

Comment: `df['X'] = df['A'].notnull().astype(int)` ?

Comment: Oh yes that was simple, also can I apply a text for the same, as str gives True or False only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example in excel:

```
=if(isnull(a2);0;1)
```

or

```
=if(a2>0;1;0)
```

(dates are aways greater then zero.